# Cannot find module '../test/tests.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

Tags: json, import, tsconfig, tsc

I have an error when trying to import a json file into a typescript file.

My tsconfig.json file contains "esModuleInterop": true, "resolveJsonModule": true.

I have tried both

```
import * as uiObject from '../test/tests.json';
```

and

```
import uiObject from '../test/tests.json';
```

Comment: Are you also using `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

Comment: No I wasn't, but I added the line and the error is the same.